# WordPress grayscale specific image size

Tags: php, wordpress, image-processing, grayscale

**What to do:** add a new image size and grayscale this specific size.

**What I've done so far:**
I've been searching around and found this helpfull URLs:
[wpbeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-grayscale-images-in-wordpress/), [Ryan Berry](https://coderwall.com/p/z6l8ba). The second solution creates a grayscale image for each size on every new image and is nearly what I'm searching for.

**The Problem:** I know how to add a new image size and the above functions creating grayscale images. What I don't know is how to add this filter *just* to a specific size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code from wpbeginner, it seems it only grayscales image which is specified as `themename-bw-image`, as seen from here (line 04):

```
$file = trailingslashit($file['path']).$meta['sizes']['themename-bw-image']['file'];
```

So I suppose if you don't want the image to get grayscaled, you could add a new image size:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','themename_bw_size');
function themename_bw_size() {
    add_image_size('themename-bw-image', 100, 100, true);
    add_image_size('other-nongrayscaled-image', 150, 150, true);
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Couldn't believe it was that easy. Thank you very much.